# Flask AssertionError While Trying to "POST"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-mail, turi-create

I am brand new to python as of about 3 days ago and I need to build a prototype python server for an iOS work project. I followed a [tutorial](https://gorillalogic.com/blog/how-to-build-a-face-recognition-app-in-ios-using-coreml-and-turi-create-part-2/#comment-1444a) for the initial build.

When I perform a "POST" request, I get an error. Here is my full code, followed by the error I'm receiving in the Terminal when a "POST" request is submitted.

PS. also fairly new to stack overflow so I'm sorry if I'm asking this question incorrectly

````
    import flask
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES, configure_uploads
from flask import make_response
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import turicreate as tc
import sys
from queue import Queue
import os
import uuid
import logging
from flask import send_from_directory
import threading
from marshmallow import fields
from marshmallow import post_load

app = Flask(__name__)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Only for debugging while developing
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)

#configure logging
logging.basicConfig( level=logging.DEBUG,
                     format='[%(levelname)s] - %(threadName)-10s : %(message)s')

#configure images destination folder
app.config['UPLOADED_IMAGES_DEST'] = './images'
images = UploadSet('images', IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, images)

#configure sqlite database
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'facerecognition.sqlite')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

#model/users is a many to many relationship,  that means there's a third #table containing user id and model id
users_models = db.Table('users_models',
                        db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                        db.Column("model_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('model.version'))
                        )
# model table
class Model(db.Model):
    version = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(100))
    users = db.relationship('User', secondary=users_models)

# user table
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300))
    position = db.Column(db.String(300))

    def __init__(self, name, position):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position

#user schema
class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'position')
#model schema
class ModelSchema(ma.Schema):
    version = fields.Int()
    url = fields.Method("add_host_to_url")
    users = ma.Nested(UserSchema, many=True)
    # this is necessary because we need to append the current host to the model url
    def add_host_to_url(self, obj):
        return request.host_url + obj.url

#initialize everything
user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)
model_schema = ModelSchema()
models_schema = ModelSchema(many=True)
db.create_all()

#error handlers
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'not found'}), 404)

@app.errorhandler(400)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'bad request'}), 400)

#register user
@app.route("/testImages/face-recognition/api/v1.0/user/register", methods=['POST'])
def register_user():
    if not request.form or not 'name' in request.form:
        return make_response(jsonify({'status': 'failed', 'error': 'bad request', 'message:' : 'Name is required'}), 400)
    else:
        name = request.form['name']
        position = request.form.get('position')
        if position is None:
            position = ""
        newuser = User(name, position)
        db.session.add(newuser)
        db.session.commit()
        if 'photos' in request.files:
            uploaded_images = request.files.getlist('photos')
            save_images_to_folder(uploaded_images, newuser)
        return jsonify({'status' : 'success', 'user' :  user_schema.dump(newuser).data })

#function to save images to image directory
def save_images_to_folder(images_to_save, user):
    for a_file in images_to_save:
        # save images to images folder using user id as a subfolder name
        images.save(a_file, str(user.id), str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.')

    # get the last trained model
    model = Model.query.order_by(Model.version.desc()).first()
    if model is not None:
        # increment the version
        queue.put(model.version + 1)
    else:
        # create first version
        queue.put(1)

    @app.route("/testImages/face-recognition/api/v1.0/model/info" , methods=['GET'])
    def get_model_info():
        models_schema.context['request'] = request
        model = Model.query.order_by(Model.version.desc()).first()
        if model is None:
            return make_response(jsonify({'status': 'failed', 'error': 'model is not ready'}), 400)
        else:
            return jsonify({'status' : 'success', 'model' : model_schema.dump(model).data})

#serve models
@app.route('/models/')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory('models', filename, as_attachment=True)



def train_model():
    while True:
        #get the next version
        version = queue.get()
        logging.debug('loading images')
        data = tc.image_analysis.load_images('images', with_path=True)

        # From the path-name, create a label column
        data['label'] = data['path'].apply(lambda path: path.split('/')[-2])

        # use the model version to construct a filename
        filename = 'Faces_v' + str(version)
        mlmodel_filename = filename + '.mlmodel'
        models_folder = 'models/'

        # Save the data for future use
        data.save(models_folder + filename + '.sframe')

        result_data = tc.SFrame( models_folder + filename +'.sframe')
        train_data = result_data.random_split(0.8)

        #the next line starts the training process
        model = tc.image_classifier.create(train_data, target='label', model='resnet-50', verbose=True)

        db.session.commit()
        logging.debug('saving model')
        model.save( models_folder + filename + '.model')
        logging.debug('saving coremlmodel')
        model.export_coreml(models_folder + mlmodel_filename)

        # save model data in database
        modelData = Model()
        modelData.url = models_folder + mlmodel_filename
        classes = model.classes
        for userId in classes:
            user = User.query.get(userId)
            if user is not None:
                modelData.users.append(user)
        db.session.add(modelData)
        db.session.commit()
        logging.debug('done creating model')
        # mark this task as done
        queue.task_done()

#configure queue for training models
queue = Queue(maxsize=0)
thread = threading.Thread(target=train_model, name='TrainingDaemon')
thread.setDaemon(False)
thread.start()```
````

Here is the Error I get In the Terminal

```
[DEBUG] - TrainingDaemon : loading images
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jan/2020 11:52:39] "POST /testImages/face-recognition/api/v1.0/user/register HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[INFO] - Thread-3   : 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jan/2020 11:52:39] "POST /testImages/face-recognition/api/v1.0/user/register HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/GorillaFace/app.py", line 103, in register_user
    save_images_to_folder(uploaded_images, newuser)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/GorillaFace/app.py", line 121, in save_images_to_folder
    @app.route("/testImages/face-recognition/api/v1.0/model/info" , methods=['GET'])
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1314, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 90, in wrapper_func
    "A setup function was called after the "
AssertionError: A setup function was called after the first request was handled.  This usually indicates a bug in the application where a module was not imported and decorators or other functionality was called too late.
To fix this make sure to import all your view modules, database models and everything related at a central place before the application starts serving requests.
Exception in thread TrainingDaemon:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/GorillaFace/app.py", line 159, in train_model
    model = tc.image_classifier.create(train_data, target='label', model='resnet-50', verbose=True)
  File "/Users/me/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/turicreate/toolkits/image_classifier/image_classifier.py", line 225, in create
    raise TypeError('"dataset" must be of type SFrame.')
TypeError: "dataset" must be of type SFrame.
```

What I've tried:

Like I said I'm still new to python so I don't know much about troubleshooting python code. The assertion error seems to be saying something was not imported correctly, so I re-installed, flask-uploads,Flask-SQLAlchemy,flask-marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy. I also made sure all the imports looked like it did in the tutorial.

Anyone have any ideas as to what I need to do to not get this error? what this code should do is allow me to post a name, position, and photos to the server which will then train a ML model to recognize the new photos.

Comment: error shows in which line it has problem - `model = tc.image_classifier.create(...)` - and it has problem with `"dataset" must be of type SFrame.` SO use at least `print()` and `print(type(..))` to check variable which you use in this line and see if you use `SFrame`

Comment: Yup! that was it. train_data = result_data.random_split(0.8) was of type tuple. So when I plugged it into

 model = tc.image_classifier.create(train_data, target='label', model='resnet-50', verbose=True), 

it didnt work. changing train_data to train_data[0], fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error shows in which line it has problem

```
model = tc.image_classifier.create(...)
```

and it has problem with

```
"dataset" must be of type SFrame.
```

so use at least `print()` and `print(type(..))` to check variablse which you use in this line and see if you use `SFrame`.